# Grails: save to Database without page reloading

Tags: database, grails, save

How can i save the textfields and checkboxes to the DB without reloading the page?

Just to click on the button and then its in the DB. Nothing more. I don't get it. This means when I have a textfield where I type in a content -> then click the button, the content from the textfield should be in the DB and should do nothing more (not reloading the page, or go to top for example).

I don't get it.

#### EDIT:

When I have a a `<div>` tag with the `id="testid"` in the standard create.gsp:

```
def create() {
  def mytestInstance = new Mytest(params)
}
```

and the `<g:remoteLink>` which should save this part looks like:

```
<g:remoteLink class="button" name="myForm" update="testid"
              url="[controller:'mytest', action: 'create']" value="....." />
```

That does not work because the page is refreshing or something like this and the things are not stored in the DB, plus they are not in the textfields any more.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [the `formRemote` tag](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formRemote.html) to send the data to a controller via Ajax

#### Edit

As it says on that page;

> This tag also requires the use of either the `<g:javascript/>`([link](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/javascript.html)) or `<g:setProvider/>`([link](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/setProvider.html)) tags. See the [AJAX section of the user guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#ajax) to find out more.

Have you done that?

Comment: Hi tim, thank you for your answear.
Well when I have a a <div>-tag with the id="testid" in the standard  create.gsp:
`code`    def create() {
  def mytestInstance = new Mytest(params)

    } `/code`  

and the <g:remoteLink> which should save this part looks like:

<g:remoteLink class="button" name="myForm" update="testid"
       url="[controller:'mytest', action: 'create']"
        value="....." />

That does not work because the page is refreshing or something like this and the things are not stored in the DB, plus they are not in the textfields any more.

Comment: @manuzi1 Code is best added to the existing question above (you can edit it). It's impossible to read in comments :-(

Comment: Ok i did it :D Sry I am new here

Comment: @manuzi1 no worries :-)  Have you done the things it says you need to do on the formRemote page? (updated my answer to point to them)

Comment: Ok hehe. Yes well, I think so because I used jQuery. Or does that mean, that the formRemote Tag has to be inside the <g:javascript> Tag? I included the jquery library in the <head> Tag. I am not sure if I am right.

Answer (score 2):

Use `<g:formRemote>` or `<g:submitToRemote>` to do the form submission with an Ajax call.

Comment: Hi Ian, maybe you can help me, I have added something ;)